# Can you run a JavaFX 13 application with a main method that calls launch (like in JavaFX 8)?

Tags: javafx

In JavaFX 8 one could just run a class that had a main method that called the static launch method on Application.class

Can this be done with JavaFX13? Right now i am doing it with the maven plugin and javafx:run but it is a bit annoying. Using NetBeans 11

have 3 dependencies on the project pom

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
        <version>13.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>13.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>13.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Once i package my project into a JAR file, how do i run the main class that extends application from command line (without maven)?

Comment: Remember that JavaFX is only a library—a big, platform-dependent library, but still just a library. The point being that a JavaFX application is still a Java application which means the main method is the entry point. Maven doesn't do anything special here. In other words, yes you can still have a main method which calls `launch`. It's the fact you can _forgo_ the main method as long as the main class extends `Application` that's remarkable and special. This functionality is built into the JDK specially for JavaFX, but because of the separation in Java 11 it may be deprecated in the future.

Comment: To clarify about Maven: What I mean is that the tool doesn't launch the application in some special way that would allow or disallow the presence of a main method; it does, however, configure and add the necessary command line arguments (e.g. `--module-path`) in order to run the application—arguments you'd have to manually input if you were to directly use the `java` executable.

Comment: The project is a maven project (using NetBeans 11) and javafx is a library like apache-commons-lang, so if it is listed as a compile time dependency, why are apache-commons-lang on the classpath at runtime but when i try to run the application via main method i get:  "Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application", what is it that maven is not adding to the runtime classpath that the maven goal jfx:run from the maven-javafx-plugin does?

Comment: If you're using the classpath then your main class cannot be a subclass of `Application`. Create a separate main class where the main method simply calls `Application.launch(YourAppClass.class, args)`.

Comment: So brilliant Slaw, you are right, it works, just put the main method somewhere else and no 'JavaFX rutime compoenents missing' Long Life JavaFX. 
Do you know why the main method cannot be in a class that is a subclass of Application?

Comment: It's an (intentional?) quirk of the implementation which allows you to not declare a main method (so long as the main class is a subclass of `Application`). If the main class is a subclass of `Application` the runtime checks if the `javafx.graphics` module is in the boot layer; when using the classpath that module doesn't exist, thus the error.

Comment: Slaw, what is the "boot layer"? when you run an application from the command line, how do you specify the "boot layer"?

Comment: See [`ModuleLayer#boot()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ModuleLayer.html#boot()) (and also the class documentation, which links to other related classes/concepts). Unless you're manually creating module layers, or using some framework that creates module layers, all modules are in the boot layer. This includes the classes on both the `--module-path` and `--class-path`. That said, classes on the `--class-path` end up in what is known as the "unnamed module".

Answer (score 0):

You can run a Java 13 application with JavaFX from command line.
How to do so, depends on your project setup.

- if your project is a java module as well, you should be able to define a `module-info.java` listing all you dependencies. The recommended way to run the application is to create a distinct JRE including your module and the required JavaFX modules. See here https://www.baeldung.com/jlink
- if your project is not a java module on its own, you can make things work using the classpath and additional module directories.

I use the following JVM options to start my GUI application directly from my IDE using the JDK. The same options should also apply when you run your application from a jar file.

```
--add-opens=javafx.graphics/javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED
--module-path /opt/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib
--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.web
```

This way, my code loaded via classpath is able to access `javafx.scene` package. For this to work I also had to configure the module path so java can find the JavaFX modules, and last but not least I had to add the modules from the JavaFX module path.

The `jlink` options for creating a custom JRE are similar.

You might have to use additional `add-opens` depending on what your application is doing.